# What is the meaning of -n in IF statement

Tags: bash

```
bash>BRANCH_NAME="My/Test/Branch/Name"
bash>if [ -n "${BRANCH_NAME}" ]; then echo ${BRANCH_NAME}; else echo "latest"; fi
```

Result

```
bash>"My/Test/Branch/Name"
```

What is the purpose of `-n` and where can I find some documentation on it? I am guessing that the flag is checking for a null or empty string.

Comment: The opposite: for *not*-empty string. `-z` is for empty string.

Comment: It may look odd, but the `if` construct evaluates the result of a command, and `[` is a command. Knowing this, in Bash you can try `help [`, which will tell you that `[` is a synonym of `test`, then...

Comment: @muru I dont think that this is a duplicate of the other question mentioned. This question is much more narrowly focused and specifically asking about -n and getting an answer specific to the question.

Comment: I agree. This is not a duplicate of the linked question. It is a different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's described in the man page under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`:

> string
>    -n string
>                True if the length of string is non-zero.